# Enabling WebAPI CORS for Angular 2 authentification

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, typescript, cors

I've seen a few answers on stackoverflow and I'm lost.

I have webapi 2 + standalone angular 2
webapi project is from template. the only thing i've changed is that i added CORS
and following line to IdentityConfig.cs > ApplicationUserManager Create()

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost:3000" });
```

here I've all standard from template:

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

On the client side I have function to get access token, that works properly:

```
authenticate(loginInfo: Login): boolean {

        let headers = new Headers(); 
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'Token', 'grant_type=password&username=alice2@example.com&password=Password2!',
            {
                headers: headers
            })
            .subscribe(
                data => this.saveAuthToken(<AccessToken>(data.json())),
                err => this.handleError(err),
                () => console.log('authentication Complete')
        );           

        return true;        
    }
```

And get function, that works ok without authentication (commented code) :

```
get(url: string) {         

    var jwt = sessionStorage.getItem(this.idTokenName);
    var authHeader = new Headers();       
    if (jwt) {
        authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
    }        

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + url, {
            headers: authHeader
        })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);       

    //return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + url)
    //    .map(res => res.json())
    //    .catch(this.handleError);   
}
```

But when i try to add Authorization header server returns:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3868/api/values. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

How to allow user to authenticate through Angular properly?

Comment: Nevermind... you should use this `[EnableCors(origins: "http://myclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", 
    methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]` as described here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#credentials

Comment: the same "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3868/api/values. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405"

Comment: Hi I deleted earlier comment.. did you remove your custom header setting in IdentityConfig and follow the instruction at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#credentials instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
2. Add to App_Start > Startup.Auth.cs > ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)

   ```
      app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
   ```

Only one line. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly add the needed headers and methods:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
    new[] { "Content-Type, Authorization" }
);

context.Response.Headers.Add(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
    new[] { "GET, POST, OPTIONS" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to the globalasax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
   var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   var res = HttpContext.Current.Response;

   var val = res.Headers.GetValues("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
   if (val == null)
   {
      if (!req.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("token") || (req.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("token") && req.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"))
      {
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
      }
   }

   if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
   {
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
      res.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");

      res.StatusCode = 200;
      res.End();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When talking to webapi angular and using a http post that either contains non-standard body contents (i.e json) or authentication then a pre-flight request is set that basically says 'am i okay to send the actual request'. Now there are several ways around this that essentially involve short cuts - use IE (if the server is on the same machine as IE ignores the port when deciding what the same machine is) or open CORS up to permit all (which is dangerous as the granting permission to an authenticated user opens your system up to all manner of hacks).

Anyway the solution we used was to add a method to the Globals.asax.cs on the server

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            var origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];

            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type, withcredentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE");

            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Now the above is checking for the pre-flight very specifically and if it finds it it adds permissions to send the next request. On your system you may need to tweek the Allow_Headers request (easiest way is to use your browser f12 to look at what headers your pre-flight request is actually sending out.

Note that the above just deals with the pre-flight CORS will still apply for the actual http POST which will need correctly handling. For this we added the server we wanted to allow in to settings and then added the System.Web.Http.Cors to the WebApiConfig Register method as follows

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(Properties.Settings.Default.CORSOriginPermittedSite, "*", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

This avoids hard coding the site which a production system really wants to avoid.

Anyway hopefully that will help.