# Angular 2 XMLHttpRequest

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a POST request to an API and I'm receiving this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://*. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
However, when I try to make a GET request, it works.

My get method:

```
getMethod() {
    return this.http.get<PerfilModel[]>(globals.BASE_URL + 'perfis');
}
```

My post method:

```
updateMethod(changePass: ChangePassModel) {
    let h = new Headers();
    h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http2.post(globals.BASE_URL + 
                           'users/passwords/redefinitions/' + 
                           changePass.key, JSON.stringify(changePass),      
                           { headers: h }
                           ).map(res => res.json);
}
```

observation: the cors toggle plugin is activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the browser same origin policy, so I disabled the security with the flag: --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax. The client should not repeat this request without modification.

May be server side they are allowing the post method.

Comment: From what I know, the server side is in C#, do you know what kind of configuration does they need to do on the server side to allow my request?

Comment: I hope u r not working backend. kindly check check with u r back end persons(server side)

Answer (score 1):

```
globals.BASE_URL + 'users/passwords/redefinitions/' + changePass.key + '/'
```

if the cors toggle plugin is activated in your backend,your url missing **"/"** at last,can you check that

Comment: Can you add your back end cors headers configuration

Comment: Authorization, Auth, Token, Access-Token, Access_Token, AccessToken, Code

Comment: You missed 'Content-Type' can you please check that

Comment: can you look at this post for your backend https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465048/7261317

Comment: Ok, I'll pass this to the back end guys and as soon as they answer I'll come back.

Comment: The back end guys told us to initialize google chrome withouth security, then we used the flag: --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="" and it worked! Thanks for the help.