# Table didn't show row result even though API is working

Tags: sql-server, angular

I am using Angular 11.0.2 to show table from Sql-server.
Sql server works fine and the API shown the result.
But when I tried to show the table in the Angular, table row didn't show.

In name.component.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DepartmentId</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of DepartmentList">
            <td>{{dataItem.DepartmentId}}</td>
            <td>{{dataItem.DepartmentName}}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I assume its because of the `ngFor`
So I tried multiple suggestion online, but still not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-dep',
  templateUrl: './show-dep.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-dep.component.css']
})
export class ShowDepComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { }

  DepartmentList:any=[];


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshDepList();
  }

  refreshDepList(){
    this.service.getDepList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.DepartmentList=data;
    });
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling WebAPI CORS for Angular 2 authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452801/enabling-webapi-cors-for-angular-2-authentification)

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour Nope. After added it, even the route not working.

Comment: @silver_river test with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour  Ralpharoo Thank you for helping. I redo evertyhing, then all good. Mybe I missed some step. Still, I learn other things.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the async pipe to the ngFor directive

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ,

```
this.DepartmentList=data.Data
```